# Best JOIN performance on Google BigQuery

Tags: mysql, join, google-bigquery, semi-join

I have two large tables, a base table and a table I'm using to filter. I want the keys where 'my_filter' is true.

Which one gives me the best performance Google BigQuery?

## Standard Join

```
select
[fields]
from base_table
join filter_table
on filter_table.my_key = base_table.my_key
where filter_table.my_filter
```

## Join on a subquery

```
select
[fields]
from base_table
join (
  select my_key from filter_table where my_filter
) filter_table
on filter_table.my_key = base_table.my_key
```

## Semi-join

```
select
[fields]
from base_table
where my_key in (
  select my_key from filter_table where my_filter
)
```

For context: the [Google BQ docs discuss semi-joins](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#semi-joins) but don't explain why you would use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got curious with your question and decided to run a test in our BQ to see how results would change.

I've simulated a query, hopefully it does a similar job to what you proposed. It processed 169 GBs of data with no caching enabled. Here's the results I found:

**Standard Join: 10.2s**

[image]

**Join on Subquery: 10.6s**

[image]

**Semi Join: 10.2s**

[image]

**Conclusion**

As Elliott said, try using Standard SQL. Other than that, BigQuery will, for the most part, regardless of your query, process everything in a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The first one will have the worst performance, when using legacy SQL with BigQuery, since filters are not pushed through joins. Use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead, which has automatic filter pushdown through joins. The third query is only equivalent if each key from the left appears at most one in the right table; otherwise it will return fewer rows than the first two queries do.